# Dynamic MVC [authorization] for multiple domains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, dynamic, dns, authorization

I am currently developing an MVC intranet web app.  The same web app will be deployed across multiple domains.  I am using windows authorization and authorizing against groups in app's local domain. I am decorating my controller actions with the [authorize] attribute to protect certain actions.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = @"Domain1\AppUsers")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Because this app will soon be deployed to Domain2, this means I will have to redecorate all of my authorized controller actions.  I would rather not have to deploy different code to each domain. Is there a way to make my authorization attribute "domain aware?"

One thought I had considered was setting the domain name in the web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="AppDomainSecurityContext" value="Domain1"/>
</appSettings>
```

And then recalling it into the controller and storing it as a string

`string AppDomainSecurityContext = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppDomainSecurityContext"].ToString();`

But then how do I get that variable into the authorize attribute...

`[Authorize(Roles = "" + AppDomainSecurityContext + "\AppUsers")]`

Doesn't work.  Is there a better way?  Suggestions?

Comment: Looks like MVC attributes [require constant expressions](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/12/12/more-c-attribute-annoyances/). SO, I'm not going to be able to use a variable.  Writing my own [Custom Authorize Attribute](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes) seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is *no need* to specify a domain.  If you use

[Authorize(Roles = "AppUsers")]

MVC4 will check against the local domain controller.